# Is there a way to change the title bar theme to dark in PyQT5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, darkmode

Windows has three title bar theme modes, dark, light, custom color. I was wondering if I could change the title bar in my pyqt5 app to use the dark theme.

I know of the qt.conf file method where you put:

```
[Platforms]
WindowsArguments = darkmode=1
```

to do dark theme if windows dark mode is on. But is this available for PyQT5 as well?

Top = windows dark title bar (disregard the tab)

bottom = My app (currently)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv + ['-platform', 'windows:darkmode=1'])
```

Or you can use the library
[Pywinstyles](https://github.com/Akascape/py-window-styles).
An example of using it is shown below:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton
import pywinstyles

app = QApplication([])

main_win = QMainWindow()
main_win.resize(600, 400)

#apply dark theme
pywinstyles.apply_style(main_win,"dark")

push_button = QPushButton("Pywinstyles")
main_win.setCentralWidget(push_button)
main_win.show()

app.exec_()
```

I hope I helped someone.